# Laravel, How to get result from controller using ajax by sending multiple values from checkboxes

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have select box which is working fine and sending values to controller but I want to use checkboxes instead of this select box and without using any submit button so this is what I need to do

I tried to use ajax and checkboxes but cant get html data as its working now with my code when Im using the select box

```
     <select class="offer-multiple" style="width: 100%" name="categories[]" id="categories" multiple="multiple">
                                @foreach($categories as $item)
                                    @if(in_array($item->id,$categoryArray))
                                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}" selected="selected">  {{ $item->title }} - {{ $item->num_offer }} Offer</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value="{{ $item->id }}">   {{ $item->title }} - {{ $item->num_offer }} Offer</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#categories").change(function() {

//console.log(locationUrl);
var dataArray = [];

var dataString = JSON.stringify($("#categories").val());

var urlCall = '/getOfferCategory/'+locationUrl[5];

console.log(urlCall);

var loadingSection = 'result';
//call ajax
makeAjaxCall(urlCall,dataString,'',loadingSection);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that is an appropriate way to use checkboxes.  You can have checkboxes having the same name if you use name[] as the name so it submits an array to the server (PHP anyways).

The markup would be something like below, but that includes a submit button.  With the checkbox option, how are you suppose to know when the user is done making selections ?  The user would have to click a submit button or something when they are done making selections ?

```
<form action="" method="" class="form" id="form">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Check Boxes with Same Name</legend>

    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" />1</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2" /> 2</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3" /> 3</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4" /> 4</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="5" /> 5</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="6" /> 6</label>
    </p>

    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">
    Submit
    </button>

</form>
```

The jQuery would be something like:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var urlCall = '/getOfferCategory/action';

$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/html/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:  "HTML",
    data:  $('#form').serialize()
}).done(function (result, status, xhr) {
    alert(result);
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
});
});
```

/echo/html/ is for Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately I'm new to using ajax and I don't know how to get data from controller